# Get a set of "static" random values everyday

Tags: android, math, random

This is a question for all those good at manipulating randomization. I am making an app in Android. For this app, I need to generate random values with the following conditions:

- I need to generate 13 random values
- I need to get a new set of these 13 random values every day (based on the system of the users device). During the entire day, these 13 values must not change.
- I need to generate these values locally i.e. user can't connect to the internet to get a value online.
- The difficult part now: I need these values to be "unique" for each day: the 13 random values that user 1 gets must be the same as the 13 values that user 2 gets.
- Each value has its own range (some are [1-100], others are [1-40])

My first hypothesis for the solution is to use a combination of dates values from the device system (day in year, day in the month, day in week etc) since these will be identical for every users. I cannot use hours, minutes or seconds though as the 13 values need to remain the same for a full day (they only change the next day, based on the device system).

I would love to read your thoughts.

Thanks

EDIT: It is ok if values are different between timezones.

Comment: How can each user get unique values if  it is based on the system of the device?

Comment: Just a though, what if users dont have a same date on their system because of the time zone differences (or just for fun/hack)?

Comment: @kaya: system data should be used to determine the current day, nothing else.

Comment: @Hemmo: thanks for poiting this out: I have edited my question with the following: It is ok if values are different between timezones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers from commonly used [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) are [pseudorandom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). This means they are predictable, for the given seed. You can set the seed equal to number of days since some point in time. For example, since [1 January 1970](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Then take 13 pseudorandom values. They will be all the same on all devices in that day. Next day, you create another `Random` with seed + 1, take 13 pseudorandom values and so on.

Comment: Definitely looks like a good idea Adam, but aren't the value going to increase if I add +1 everyday? I need to avoid any feeling of trend from one day to another

Comment: @Kintaro You are adding value to the seed, not to the pseudorandom values itself so there is no trend in the values, just in seed which doesn't matter. Check for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed

Comment: Yes of course the seed value must change, my bad. Thanks for your answer, this is what I've implemented and it seems to work with some testing

Answer (score 0):

What you think is probably the most straightforward approach. A simple seed would be fine for most things.

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); 
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
long seed = cal.getTime().getTime();
```